# Want to have a cancel button to cancel any changes made to specific row

Tags: angular

In my angular project, there is an array from a db that is displayed into a table. Whenever you click on a row, it is changed, using `ngSwitch`, from a display component to an edit component. In the edit component, I want to implement a button that will cancel any changes that have been made to that row and set the data in the row back to how it was before. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Please show what you have tried with

Comment: @MarcusH I haven't tried anything currently, I'm not really sure how I would go about doing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When switching to "edit mode", duplicate the data into another data object / array and display that data instead. On save, do what you normally do and update your main data collection; on cancel, just clear your edited data object.

I.E.

```ts
myDataCollection: myDataObject[];
myEditedData: myDataObject;

edit(id: string): void {
  const data = his.myDataCollection.find(a => a.id === id);
  if(!data) return; // make sure the data / ID is valid
  this.myEditedData = new myDataObject(data); // copy constructor, 
  // or use a clone() method or something so it's
  // not a reference to the same object as the original

  // switch to edit mode in template
  // (this can be done by checking "myEditedData?.id === data.id" in a
  //   *ngFor="let data of myDataCollection")
}

cancelEditing(): void {
  this.myEditedData = null;
  // switch from edit mode in template
}

saveEdits(): void {
  //                                      | where "setTo" is you function to 
  //                                      v copy another object's properties
  this.myDataCollection.find(a => a.id === id).setTo(this.myEditedData);
  this.myEditedData = null; // or publish your edits back to the db,
                            // then set to null.
}
```

Though if you are using separate components for "displaying" and "editing", then make the editing-component have `myData` and `myEditedData`, and just switch the `myDataCollection.find(...)` statements to just reference `myData`. You'll also have to have a "changed" event or something to pass back to the parent component to update its data collection with the new object as well.